# High rate of ping timeouts & packet loss

Tags: network, wifi

I've been experiencing a painfull low internet speed on my Air 11" Late 2010 with the Sierra 10.12.2. Neither my phone nor other user's computers on the network are experiencing this issue. Prior to this problem occurring, I used a non-official network cable adapter.

I've already tried to reboot in safe mode, recreate the wifi interface. For illustration, I got

```
PING google.com (172.217.29.46): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
64 bytes from 172.217.29.46: icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=17.265 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
64 bytes from 172.217.29.46: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=26.402 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.29.46: icmp_seq=4 ttl=56 time=9.201 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
64 bytes from 172.217.29.46: icmp_seq=6 ttl=56 time=18.831 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 7
Request timeout for icmp_seq 8
64 bytes from 172.217.29.46: icmp_seq=9 ttl=56 time=27.363 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.29.46: icmp_seq=10 ttl=56 time=7.736 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 11
Request timeout for icmp_seq 12
64 bytes from 172.217.29.46: icmp_seq=13 ttl=56 time=21.891 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 14
64 bytes from 172.217.29.46: icmp_seq=15 ttl=56 time=10.362 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.29.46: icmp_seq=16 ttl=56 time=14.790 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.29.46: icmp_seq=17 ttl=56 time=21.166 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.29.46: icmp_seq=18 ttl=56 time=11.302 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.29.46: icmp_seq=19 ttl=56 time=16.252 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.29.46: icmp_seq=20 ttl=56 time=6.880 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.29.46: icmp_seq=21 ttl=56 time=13.668 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.29.46: icmp_seq=22 ttl=56 time=9.033 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.29.46: icmp_seq=23 ttl=56 time=25.206 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.29.46: icmp_seq=24 ttl=56 time=10.746 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.29.46: icmp_seq=25 ttl=56 time=11.445 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.29.46: icmp_seq=26 ttl=56 time=7.018 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.29.46: icmp_seq=27 ttl=56 time=15.381 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.29.46: icmp_seq=28 ttl=56 time=6.940 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.29.46: icmp_seq=29 ttl=56 time=9.572 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.29.46: icmp_seq=30 ttl=56 time=13.075 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.29.46: icmp_seq=31 ttl=56 time=10.607 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.29.46: icmp_seq=32 ttl=56 time=18.697 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 33
64 bytes from 172.217.29.46: icmp_seq=34 ttl=56 time=16.847 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.29.46: icmp_seq=35 ttl=56 time=16.268 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.29.46: icmp_seq=36 ttl=56 time=11.843 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 37
Request timeout for icmp_seq 38
Request timeout for icmp_seq 39
64 bytes from 172.217.29.46: icmp_seq=40 ttl=56 time=12.897 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 41
64 bytes from 172.217.29.46: icmp_seq=42 ttl=56 time=12.243 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 43
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
45 packets transmitted, 30 packets received, 33.3% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 6.880/14.364/27.363/5.655 ms
```

From Facebook:

```
PING facebook.com (157.240.12.35): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
64 bytes from 157.240.12.35: icmp_seq=2 ttl=56 time=29.464 ms
64 bytes from 157.240.12.35: icmp_seq=3 ttl=56 time=23.190 ms
64 bytes from 157.240.12.35: icmp_seq=4 ttl=56 time=14.754 ms
64 bytes from 157.240.12.35: icmp_seq=5 ttl=56 time=21.304 ms
64 bytes from 157.240.12.35: icmp_seq=6 ttl=56 time=21.721 ms
64 bytes from 157.240.12.35: icmp_seq=7 ttl=56 time=14.804 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 8
Request timeout for icmp_seq 9
Request timeout for icmp_seq 10
64 bytes from 157.240.12.35: icmp_seq=11 ttl=56 time=24.932 ms
^C
--- facebook.com ping statistics ---
12 packets transmitted, 7 packets received, 41.7% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 14.754/21.453/29.464/4.906 ms
```

Comment: I don't understand...you say you used a "non-official network cable adapter" but then provide the ping results for a "re-created WiFi adapter."  What does that mean?

Comment: No, it was just a comment. I used it the day before the problem show up, don't know if could be related so I gave the info